# Copper plumbing component Identification

Tags: plumbing

Does anyone happen to know what the component that I circled here. It is a simple thing that I need to buy to go around a 7/8 inch OD copper pipe.

Also - where would I go to get one?

[image]

Comment: that looks like it is  custom made for the device in the picture ..... what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 7):

It's called a Square O Strap. The one in your picture is already "set" in place so ones bought separately will need to be soldered to the pipe.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a wall plate that can be screwed in place to help hold the pipe. Sometimes those are used when pipes will have a lot of movement like a water spigot. From the looks of the fitting you have there, this pipe will not be moved around very much after installation is complete. If the piping is strong, just go back with an [**escutcheon**](https://www.signaturehardware.com/bathroom/plumbing-and-parts/escutcheons-and-flanges.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAyrXiBRAjEiwATI95ma0GRyyknLCWFR9fyIjmHAm-yQpYizrIW4QRo9jYUxgL-NsPfDm2dxoCO3kQAvD_BwE). AKA remodelers plate or smitty plate. They come in many designs and are available at any plumbing or building supply store.

[image: 7/8 Escutcheon]

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessarily a separate part - you can purchase pre-assembled "copper stub outs" which include the bent copper pipe & the mounting bracket already installed.

They come with a variety of fittings on the open end - sweat, PEX fittings, push-to-connect, etc.